# xamarin forms previewer is showing a MockView after rendering

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms

I'm not be able to see my design screen in the xamarin froms previewer. It is only showing a `MockView` with a orange screen with black text after rendering.

[image]

I don't get any errors about it?

- 64 bit Java 8.0_121
- Visual Studio 2013
- Xamarin Stable Updates (4.3.0.789)

Comment: sorry did you get it fixed am having the same issue

Comment: @AkohVictorGutz No, I didn't get a fix...

Comment: Okay  i resulted into using gorilla player instead i made more research i saw the same problem but there was no answer. checkout the documentation for it here https://github.com/UXDivers/Gorilla-Player-Support/wiki

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by using the Debug mode instead of Release

Comment: What are you going to do when you need to release the app?

Comment: Well if you're sure the app works you will simply build the app in the Archive manager, there's no need to use the release mode.

Comment: I suppose it's not the best practice to build the app in Debug mode. Otherwise, as far as I know, all of your code is extractable from the APK (?). Also Google will not allow you to Publish such APK to Play Store. Only useful for apps you build just for personal use.

Answer (score 6):

i had the same problem,the mockview screem
just close the previewer also close any XAML page open and open the previewer again,it will fix it

Answer (score 2):

Move your viewmodel binding from the xaml file to the code behind of the XAML file. This should help get back the layout in previewer.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the Solution and Build it. This helped me.

If it does not work, Restart Visual Studio and then Clean -> Build Solution.

For Clean-Build Solution on Menubar Go to **Build -> Clean Solution**. After that Go to **Build -> Build Solution**.

Remember that doing Clean-Build only to your specific Android, iOS or UWP project might not work. You need to clean and build the entire solution that contains Android, iOS and UWP projects.

Comment: switch from release to debug mode, and then build solution works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

2020 Answer:

Answering as this keeps coming up in 2020 when searching for "xamarin android mock view"

It was a bug introduced in Xamarin Forms, see an ongoing issue here:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10224

This was possibly (not confirmed)  introduced in android X project update.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by using older version of EF v2.2.6, and it works just fine!

Answer (score -1):

Just set "Theme" -> Default [Screen: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD8bw.jpg)
I was really happy when it worked.
Maybe there are a lot of reasons of this problem. But this is one of them.

Answer (score -1):

### 2020 Answer 2.

Update Visual Studio.

I had the same problem and I have updated the Visual Studio and it helped me. The problem was solved.

Found this at [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/904999/xamarin-forms-xaml-preview-not-working-shows-orang.html):

> a fix for this issue has been released. Install the most recent
> release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads